# Google Sheets - SUMIFS using date ranges as criteria shows wrong values

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a financial overview tool in which I want to make sums of income/costs/profit - all summarised based on the month of the year in which those business cases were finished.

I ran into a problem with the SUMIFS formula not showing a correct value. Some months show correct value using a first formula, some only using the second, etc.

[Google Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BVe2Gs9FaHXu2s6iMCUHOG71qnwmnbAWJbjVwL_savg/edit?usp=sharing) (all important numbers are randomised)

**I tried three options :** (February as an example)

- `=SUMIFS(input!H3:H200;input!M3:M200;">"&DATUM(2022;1;31);input!M3:M200;"<"&DATUM(2022;3;1))`
  *=>>This way I wanted to limit the SUMIF by only choosing cells with date > January but < March*
- `=SUMIFS(input!H3:H200;input!M3:M200;">"&DATUM(2022;2;0);input!M3:M200;"<"&DATUM(2022;2;31))`
  *=>>Limiting the SUMIF by choosing cells with date range higher than 2022/2/0 and lower than 2022/2/32 (unreachable dates)*
- `=SUMIFS(input!H3:H200;input!M3:M200;">="&DATUM(2022;2;1);input!M3:M200;"<="&DATUM(2022;2;31))`
  *=>>Limiting the SUMIF by choosing cells with date range higher and including 2022/2/1 and lower + including 2022/2/31 (unreachable dates)*

*Why didnt i just refer to a cell with the sum already calculated? Because the input list is an excel export from our crm platform which is never the same and I want to create something that does the work for me.
Why didnt I use index + vlookup to simply find the sum value based on the keyword "month name" + column number? Because I need to use a similar formula as sumifs in the next columns that are not shown yet. If there is no direct solution to my problem then I will resort to using the index+vlookup.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the dates on the months that don't coincide solves the issue.

For example for May:

February 2022 had 28 days but on the function for May you used the 31st of february:

`=SUMIFS(input!G3:G200;input!M3:M200;">"&DATE(**2022;2;31**);input!M3:M200;">"&DATE(2022;4;1))`

and the result is:
[image: Table wrong]

If instead I change the March function to:
`SUMIFS(input!G3:G200;input!M3:M200;">"&DATE(2022;2;28);input!M3:M200;"<"&DATE(2022;4;1))`

[image: Table wrigt]

The result gets corrected as it should.